# how to measure memory consumption of a code or process?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performance, memory

I'm trying to measure the memory consumetion for a process using

```
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long totalBytesOfMemoryUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
```

and using PeakPagedMemorySize64 , PeakVirtualMemorySize64 , PeakWorkingSet64

but when i run the same process multiple time i get different values

```
PeakPagedMemorySize64 112758784 PeakVirtualMemorySize64 332701696   PeakWorkingSet64 143835136
PeakPagedMemorySize64 113696768 PeakVirtualMemorySize64 332636160   PeakWorkingSet64 144642048
PeakPagedMemorySize64 113528832 PeakVirtualMemorySize64 332701696   PeakWorkingSet64 144547840
```

why i have this different values instead of getting the same value each time ? And how i can optimize it to minimize this variation ?

Comment: Use the Random class to generate better numbers.  Use a book like Windows Internals to understand how the operating system manages memory.

Comment: @HansPassant don't understand what do u mean about Use the Random class, it's values which i get using Process.PeakPagedMemorySize64 , Process.PeakVirtualMemorySize64  ... I don't know which part on the book i can found what i'm looking for. do u have any idea where i can found it , in which part of the book ?